# Implementing a simple logic equation

Tags: digital-logic, data, nand

I need to do a lab that seemed like it was simple, but for some reason i cant get the right output for this function. its G(0)= T1T3'+T5T7'. These are data inputs.. I can only use NAND and NOR gates. The set up i have now is as shown below[image]

I continue to get a constant low output for G(0). I would really appreciate it if someone could let me know where the schematic is wrong. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're asked that \$G_0=T_1\overline{T_3}+T_5\overline{T_7}\$ ... However, you have \$G_0=\overline{\overline{T_1\overline{T_3}}+\overline{T_5\overline{T_7}}}\$

Answer (score 3):

Try making the final NOR gate, whose output is G(0), into a NAND, since this is a sum of products expression. If you use DeMorgan's law, you'll then see that you have two AND gates feeding into an OR, which is your original expression.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqs7Jr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The inverters can be NOR or NAND, as both perform the same inverter function here.